# Java cannot find the jasper subreport location

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am new to ireport. When I used jasper to create subreport. I could run the subreport in Designer without any problems. When I used the java to call in local machine. I encounter the exception.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location :
```

I have tried so many ways but still could not find a fix.

Comment: Do you have specified the location of the sub report on disk? Or where do you load the reports from?

Comment: I can load the report.jrxml in java with no problem. And I put the subreport .jrxml under the same folder of the  report.jrxml.

Comment: Can't you specify the full path to the subreport? Probably it is searing it in the "current" folder of your application and not the parent report

Comment: The expression class I set is java.lang.String. The SubreportExpression I set is "subreport.jasper"

Comment: I tried hard code the absolute folder path. Still not Working :(

Comment: Create a parameter in the report use your subreport "SUBREPORT_DIR". 
Then set the subreport Expresion like <$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "yourSubreport.jasper">

Comment: I have tried to use the $P{SUBREPORT_DIR} and also pass the parameter throught java. The parameter I pass is the same path of the report. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question?

How did u call your subreport through java?Did you used your main report or subreport name itself.

You can run subreport directly in ireport. But in java you have to call main report and the main report have path for subreport jasper file.

Comment: I just called the main report. And place all the subreport file under the same folder as the main report. I didn't call the subreport directly. Because when I called the main report. The main report should call the subreport automatically. But when the main report try to call the subreport. I think the system cannot find the path in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method would be to separately compile your subreport and create .jasper file , Once you have the .jasper file pass the path of the jasper file and not the jrxml and subreport will work..

> Also note that java jasper version and the version in which subreport
>   is compiled i.e Ireport version should be same...